# Ajustar elemento entre appBar y barra inferiror en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Intento realizar el siguiente diseño

```
CoordinatorLayout

 --Toolbar con imagen flexible de fondo
 --Recyclerview (ajustado entre toolbar y barra inferior)
 --Barra inferior
```

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/about_background_header"
                    android:contentDescription="default desc"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/app_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription="default desc"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_app_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/app_icon"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="app name"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_app_version"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_app_name"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="1.0.0.0001"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small.Inverse" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_sample2" />-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="copyright" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
        android:tint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

La barra inferior me solapa la vista del `recyclerView`, cómo puedo ajustar que el `reciclerView` empieze bajo la `Toolbar flexible` hasta empezar la barra inferior?.